Virtual workspace like app for organization and productivity?
I do a lot of things in different areas and one of the biggest issues is organization/productivity. What I'm looking for is some way to organize files and planning in a nice way that sorta keeps the different "routines" separate so it is easier to pick up where I left off(rather than everything getting jumped or wasting time looking for files).
What I sort of envision is some app where I can "create a workspace" which allows me to create notes, maybe audio recording, link to files, and maybe a timeline/planner like app. Maybe even with "sub workspaces" so I can go off on "tangents" within the workspace and go back to them as needed.
Maybe something like github but more tailored to acting as a sort of "virtual OS"(only for the interfacing and such).
e.g., rather than having one OS with hundreds of icons for different subject matter with subfolders and such(one for programming, one for electonics, etc) without any real organization beyond that, something more like one OS for each. This way everything is somewhat isolated. Of course I won't want to install 10 OS's and manage them all and do not need "hardware virtualization" and such. Just a way to organize groups of common files with a bit of "sauce" on top to make it more productive.
E.g., suppose I'm reading philosophy and I have 10 books I want to read. It would be nice to have a "workspace" where I can link to the files and organize them in a "reading sequence" and add some notes(text and/or voice) for thoughts, ideas, etc and maybe a bit more.
Typically I use things like Notepad++ and some audio recorders to do the notes and audio but all things exist in "one workspace"(windows OS) and so it becomes cumbersome to move around.
I can't find any software that seems to do this type of thing. Of course there is software that does parts of what I want and to the extreme(e.g., MS project, Obsidian, etc). In some sense, I suppose, if there was a sort of "app virtualizer workspace" that one could virtualize these apps then I could use them in an isolated way. It's not what I envision because it's still a bit clunky but it would keep things mostly separate.
What would be cool, for instance, is to have a combo box in windows where I could select which workplace I want and it would essentially be self-contained. I suppose "user accounts" is like that but that is a bit too clunky and slow. I've not tried it, maybe it would work but it also seems to be a bit too extreme and generally has issues with cross referencing, user permissions, etc. Hence something a bit lighter and just gets the essentials without getting in the way.
I can't find any software that works along these lines, any suggestions?
